# Dynamically populate some attributes for a set of case classes

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, shapeless

- I have a set of model classes and a subset of those models have 2 properties called `createdBy` and `modifiedBy`.
- I need to populate those attributes only for those objects that has those attributes. Currently I'm doing it in a pattern match with some boilerplate code.

```
  case class DataSourceInstanceRow(id: Int, value: String, createdBy: Option[String], modifiedBy: Option[String])
  case class FormDefinitionRow(id: Int, formData: String, createdBy: Option[String], modifiedBy: Option[String])
  case class DecisionTableDefinitionRow(id: Int, rows: Int, definitions: List[String], createdBy: Option[String], modifiedBy: Option[String])
  case class ReportDef(id: Int, reportType: Int, reportName: String)


  def populateLogs[T](t: T, user: String): T = {
    t match {
      case ds: DataSourceInstanceRow =>
        if(ds.id == -1) ds.copy(modifiedBy = Some(user), createdBy = Some(user)).asInstanceOf[T]
        else ds.copy(modifiedBy = Some(user)).asInstanceOf[T]
      case fd: FormDefinitionRow =>
        if(fd.id == -1) fd.copy(modifiedBy = Some(user), createdBy = Some(user)).asInstanceOf[T]
        else fd.copy(modifiedBy = Some(user)).asInstanceOf[T]
      case dtd: DecisionTableDefinitionRow =>
        if(dtd.id == -1) dtd.copy(modifiedBy = Some(user), createdBy = Some(user)).asInstanceOf[T]
        else dtd.copy(modifiedBy = Some(user)).asInstanceOf[T]
      case o => o
    }
  }
```

- `DataSourceInstanceRow`, `FormDefinitionRow`, `DecisiontableDefinitionRow` have `modifiedBy` and `createdBy` properties. But not `ReportDef`

How can I use shapeless to create an abstraction to remove the boilerplate from above pattern matching?

Comment: You're far more likely to get an answer if you minimize your problem and provide a working example.

Comment: @TravisBrown Thanks for the advice. I just simplified the problem. Please take a look.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this kind of thing with Shapeless's `Updater`:

```
import shapeless.{ LabelledGeneric, HList, Witness }
import shapeless.labelled.{FieldType, field}
import shapeless.ops.record.Updater

type CreatedBy = Witness.`'createdBy`.T
type ModifiedBy = Witness.`'modifiedBy`.T

def populateLogs[T, R <: HList](t: T, user: String)(implicit
  gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[T, R],
  cb: Updater.Aux[R, FieldType[CreatedBy, Option[String]], R] = null,
  mb: Updater.Aux[R, FieldType[ModifiedBy, Option[String]], R] = null
): T = (
  for {
    createdBy <- Option(cb)
    modifiedBy <- Option(mb)
  } yield gen.from(
    createdBy(modifiedBy(gen.to(t), field(Some(user))), field(Some(user)))
  )
).getOrElse(t)
```

And then:

```
scala> populateLogs(DataSourceInstanceRow(1, "abc", None, None), "foo")
res0: DataSourceInstanceRow = DataSourceInstanceRow(1,abc,Some(foo),Some(foo))

scala> populateLogs(ReportDef(1, 2, "abc"), "foo")
res1: ReportDef = ReportDef(1,2,abc)
```

This implementation uses a trick based on the fact that you can put a `null` default value on an implicit parameter and the compiler will use that if it can't find an implicit. It's simple and works just fine, but some people hate it. A more principled approach uses implicit prioritization:

```
trait UpdateBoth[T] extends ((T, String) => T)

object UpdateBoth extends LowPriorityUpdateBothInstances {
  implicit def updateWithFields[T, R <: HList](implicit
    gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[T, R],
    cb: Updater.Aux[R, FieldType[CreatedBy, Option[String]], R],
    mb: Updater.Aux[R, FieldType[ModifiedBy, Option[String]], R]
  ): UpdateBoth[T] = (t, user) =>
    gen.from(cb(mb(gen.to(t), field(Some(user))), field(Some(user))))
}

trait LowPriorityUpdateBothInstances {
  implicit def updateAny[T]: UpdateBoth[T] = (t, _) => t
}

def populateLogs[T](t: T, user: String)(implicit update: UpdateBoth[T]): T =
  update(t, user)
```

That will work exactly the same way.

Comment: Could you please explain or point to a resource that explains what's going on with `Witness.`'createdBy`.T` ?

Comment: We need a type-level symbol to select the member name, and Shapeless's `Witness` provides a macro that supports the `Witness.\`'createdBy\`.T` syntax.